# I'm having trouble with finding unique words, how to improve code?

Tags: c++

I need to count the number of unique words and with my code below, it doesn't seem to be counting correctly. I am not sure what else I can do to make it work and would really appreciate any suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using std::string;
using std::set;


unsigned long countUWords(const string& s)
{
   set<string> uw;
   string word = "";
   for(size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
       bool words = (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') || (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z');
           if(words){
               word += s[i];
           }
           else if(!words && word != ""){
               uw.insert(word);
               word = "";
           }
   }
   if (word != "")
       uw.insert(word);
   return uw.size();
}

int main ()
{
    string s;
    unsigned long UWords = 0;
    while(getline(cin, s)){
        UWords += countUWords(s);
    }
    cout << UWords << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Place all words in a dictionary, where the values are the number of occurrences. When you're done the unique ones are those with one occurrence each.

Comment: When you say "unique" do you mean "distinct", or "occurs only once"?

Comment: @Renan That's pretty much what this code is doing, except more efficiently - you don't need counts.

Comment: What is the input and what is the outputs you are getting? It would help if you can print the set UW at the end. To me it looks like you are adding a word a letter at a time, or you are really checking unique letters??

Comment: @Dukeling *"That's pretty much what this code is doing, except more efficiently"* How is it more efficient if, as the OP says, it's *"not counting correctly"*?

Comment: Haven't you ever heard of `std::isalpha`?  You do know that on
some machines (most actually), the upper and lower case letters
don't form a contiguous group of code points, and that `z` isn't
the highest code point.  (I know, this is probably
homework, where you're allowed to ignore a good bit of reality,
in order to concentrate on the issues at hand, but you still
should be using `isalpha`.)

Comment: @Renan Sorry, I partially missed the "unique" part of this. If code does one thing, I usually ignore most of the explanation that says it does another thing (because explanations are often wrong and I'm lazy). My bad. This code correctly computes the number of distinct elements, it doesn't work for uniques.

Comment: "dictionary" => `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the `for` loop you need to check if `word` is empty. If not you need to push the content of `word` inside the set.

After the end bracket of the `for` loop, add:

```
if (word != "")
    uw.insert(word);
```

As [you can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63ea340493c61a4f) it works just fine after that edit.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought I had that part in my code before. I am still having trouble printing out the correct number of unique words, however. I am thinking something is wrong within my int main().

Comment: @user2829430, nothing is wrong with your code after the edit suggested above (as showed above). If you have other errors or unexpected behavior in other parts of your code, I suggest you to create another question.

Comment: I included my int main() as I believe something is wrong with it, just not sure what exactly but I'm suspecting it's something with getline?

Comment: Oh, I figured out that this code is only looking at one line at a time and then checking for the words. It is not looking at every single line at the same time for the unique words. Now, I just need to figure out how to implement that into the code. Any suggestions?